# How to log class/method/function name in Webpack code minification conditions?

Tags: javascript, webpack

It's not always obvious from stack trace where error occurred.
So, maybe it's not meaningless to log where error has been thrown.

```js
throw new Error(ErrorsMessagesBuilder.buildErrorMessage({
  errorType: ErrorsMessagesBuilder.ErrorsTypes.invalidParameterValue,
  functionInvocationExpression: function.name,
  description: `Tasks set: '${targetTagsSetID}' is not defined in config file.`
}));
```

Unfortunately, `function.name` will be lost because of Webpack code minification. Does Webpack suggest some solutions for it?

Comment: enable source map

Comment: @arslan2012, Thank you for the comment. Is it O'K to public the source map on production?

Comment: ofc not lol, save it locally, you can add your local source map into chrome dev tool to debug online website

Comment: @arslan2012, doest it mean that source map contains the original names of fuctions/methods?

Comment: yes, please google it